# How do I return the id associated with the test json element?

Tags: json, jq

I return the following json from a curl. I've simplified the ID's however my goal is to return the id related to the test object. The desired return value is `55555`.

I'm using jq to parse the string.
https://stedolan.github.io/jq

```
[
  {
    "attributes": null,
    "id": "44444",
    "name": "production",
    "type": "system_group"
  },
  {
    "attributes": null,
    "id": "55555",
    "name": "test",
    "type": "system_group"
  },
  {
    "attributes": null,
    "id": "66666",
    "name": "uat",
    "type": "system_group"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty straightforward filter, use the `select` and `contain` constructs.

```
jq '.[] | select( .name| contains("test")) | .id'
```

Call the filter with `-r` to remove the quotes and print the raw value.

[jqplay-URL](https://jqplay.org/s/IKy-OKCpD3)